# String.StartsWith not working with tilde ("~") characters LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

For some reason, my call to IEnumerable.Where() using String.StartsWith() appears to be giving different results depending on whether it's being used in LINQ-to-SQL or standard LINQ (-to-objects). If I add in a call to ToList() on what's otherwise the same call, I get different results back:

```
var withToList = MyDataContext.MyEntities.ToList().Where(entity => entity.Name.StartsWith("~Test: My Test String"));
// withToList.Count() returns 5, which is what I expect.
var direct = MyDataContext.MyEntities.Where(entity => entity.Name.StartsWith("~Test: My Test String"));
// direct.Count() returns 0
```

It's my understanding that, unlike some of the other operators/methods in LINQ, the Where() method does *not* require the predicate to be SQL-translatable; it's executed on the client side and thus can be arbitrary .NET code. (I've certainly thrown other non-SQL code at it with successful results). I've even got a link where [Anders himself](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/128fe4cf-776d-4200-9f48-7f8dd30dcb34) suggests that this should be working. What the heck?

EDIT: I've figured out the problem; it has to do with the presence of a tilde in my search string. I've updated the title to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At Konamiman's suggestion I [checked the log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx) to see what SQL was being executed. Here's (a munged example of) what I got.

The first call executes:

```
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Name]
FROM [dbo].[MyEntity] AS [t0]
```

That makes sense, as the filtering is happening on the client-side, so we need to query for all rows.

The second call executes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[MyEntity] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Name] LIKE @p0 ESCAPE '~'
```

So, Jon Skeet was on the right track; I'm getting the problem because I happen to have a tilde in my data/query condition. This causes LINQ-to-SQL to mark it as an escape character, and thus it doesn't get used in the search. [This MSDN thread does a decent job of explaining why](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/91c32b17-3a7c-49a8-86c6-55eeb8e36674); it appears to be a bug in the LINQ-to-SQL code.

The suggested workaround is to use LINQ's SQLMethods.Like() method to change the escaping character away from "~", like so:

```
var direct = MyDataContext.MyEntities.Where(entity => SQLMethods.Like(entity.Name, "~Test: My Test String%", "!");
// direct.Count() now returns 5 as expected
```

This works, but unfortunately this is a LINQ-to-SQL *only* solution. If you try it on the LINQ-to-Object version, you get this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException : Method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String, Char)' 
cannot be used on the client; it is only for translation to SQL.
```

The same thing happens when using AsEnumerable() as Jon Skeet suggested.

I tried wrapping my StartsWith call in a method and using StartsWith with a StringComparisonOption, but these don't work on the LINQ-to-SQL side because they're not SQL-translatable. (And thus my earlier assumption about the Where() method was incorrect).

So: it looks like (until this bug is fixed) you cannot have a searching function that both works with tilde characters *and* is agnostic about the underlying flavour of LINQ. (If there is a method, please be sure to post it).

Answer (score 5):

This query *will* be executing in SQL - so you may see some oddities depending on how SQL is handling the "LIKE". I suggest you find out what query it's running, and try running it yourself in SQL Management Studio. In this case it seems unusual that it's not working though - it *could* be a bug in LINQ to SQL; it may not be escaping things properly. (Does ~ mean anything special in a SQL LIKE clause?)

Anything which is meant to be part of what's executed at the database side *does* need to be SQL-translatable. It *can't* contain arbitrary .NET code - only code which LINQ-to-SQL is able to translate. Otherwise composition gets broken - if you add a join, or an ordering etc afterwards, it would become very hard indeed to do *some* of the processing in SQL and some on the client side, mixing the two. You can do some in SQL and *then* some on the client side though. Note that you can use `AsEnumerable` as an alternative to `ToList` to get the rest of the query to be executed in-process.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, indeed the `Where` predicate doesn't need to be translatable to SQL, since you are first getting the whole table to memory (`ToList`) and then doing the filtering.

In the second case, the `Where` predicate needs to be translatable to a SQL WHERE clause, since the filtering is done in the database. `TheString.StartsWith` method is translated to a SQL LIKE statement.

Remember that [you can take a look at the generated SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx) by using the [DataContext.Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) property. This should help you to understand how it works.