# Linq for SQL is replacing % with ~%

Tags: sql, linq, c#-4.0

I have a database with firstName, middleName and lastName columns. I'm using linq for sql to query against this table, my input is the whole name,

Here is the linq query:

```
var n = customerName.Replace(" ", "%");        
var customers = from c in _db.tblCustomers
    where ((c.cSurName??"") + " " + (c.cMiddleName??"") + " "+ (c.cLastName??"")).Contains(n)
    select c;
```

With "Jan Rue" as input, this produces the following SQL where clause:

```
    WHERE (((((COALESCE([t0].[cSurName],@p0)) + @p1) 
           + (COALESCE([t0].[cMiddleName],@p2))) + @p3) 
           + (COALESCE([t0].[cLastName],@p4))) LIKE @p5 ESCAPE ''~'''
   ,N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(1),@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(1),@p4 nvarchar(4000),@p5 nvarchar(11)'
   ,@p0=N'',@p1=N' ',@p2=N'',@p3=N' ',@p4=N'',@p5=N'%Jan~%Rue%'
```

And it gives me 0 rows. If I remove the ~ it works just fine. Is there any way for me to force LINQ to not escape?

EDIT solution:

```
where SqlMethods.Like(((c.cSurName ?? "") + " " + (c.cMiddleName ?? "") + " " + (c.cLastName ?? "")), "%" + n + "%")
```

EDIT #2: found some more info: 
["Implementing a LINQ version of SQL’s LIKE Operator"](http://www.devexpertise.com/2009/09/25/implementing-a-linq-version-of-sqls-like-operator/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug logged on [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/425877/tilde-sign-search-bug-in-linq-to-sql). See "Workaround" tab.

Also see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879429/string-startswith-not-working-with-tilde-characters-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Contains("Jan%Rue") is translated as "it should contain the literal string 'Jan%Rue'", so Linq2Sql helpfully escapes that '%' inside the text for you. Only you want that '%' to mean the sql-wildcard so you don't want that escaping.

The article you found seems promising.