# c# linq query generates "ESCAPE '~'" syntax when translating "StartsWith" to sql "LIKE"

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, escaping

ora. i've got this linq syntax below that generates the sql below that. the sql server database that receives the query rejects the linq-appended "ESCAPE '~'". i'm still researching, but any perspective welcome!

```
var rc = (
    from x in dc.Candidate
    join xs in dc.CandidateStatus on x.StatusId equals xs.CandidateStatusId
    join xss in dc.CandidateStatus on xs.SystemStatusId equals xss.CandidateStatusId
    where
        _active.Contains(xss.Code)
        && (x.NickName.StartsWith(startsWith) || x.FirstName.StartsWith(startsWith))
    orderby x.NickName, x.FirstName, x.LastName
    select new ListItem {
        Id = x.CandidateId,
        Label = FormatIndividual(x.LastName,x.FirstName,x.NickName)
    });
return rc.ToList<ListItem>();

SELECT [t0].[candid] AS [Id], [t0].[lastnm] AS [lastName], [t0].[firstnm] AS [firstName], [t0].[nicknm] AS [nickName]
FROM [ats].[cand] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [ats].[candstatus] AS [t1] ON [t0].[statusid] = ([t1].[candstatusid])
INNER JOIN [ats].[candstatus] AS [t2] ON [t1].[sysstatid] = ([t2].[candstatusid])
WHERE ([t2].[code] IN (@p0, @p1, @p2)) AND (([t0].[nicknm] LIKE @p3 ESCAPE '~') OR ([t0].[firstnm] LIKE @p4 ESCAPE '~'))
ORDER BY [t0].[nicknm], [t0].[firstnm], [t0].[lastnm]
```

implemented below. removed need for sql server wildcard ('%' - ie, what was being escaped).

```
        ...
        //&& (x.NickName.StartsWith(startsWith) || x.FirstName.StartsWith(startsWith))
        && (x.NickName.Substring(0,1).Equals(startsWith) || x.FirstName.Substring(0,1).Equals(startsWith))
        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx - See: C. Using the ESCAPE clause

The `~` char is being used as the escape character for the value in `@p3`.

Comment: i thought something like that, but there's no need for it. is there a way to excise it before it hits sql server?

Comment: it is added if the value in `startsWith` contains characters than need escaping, e.g. `%`. What values are you passing in for `startsWith`?

Comment: here's another question thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879429/string-startswith-not-working-with-tilde-characters-linq-to-sql

Comment: ah, DUH on me. i do use '%' because it's "starts with". oh knowledgeable one, where and how can i remediate that? the query returns no data, but if i remove the "ESCAPE" and run it directly against the db, it returns lots. the other examples i've seen, i've no idea where i can apply "@" or such...

Comment: ah! you're fast! (this site is great...) i'll read/apply the link now. thanks!

Comment: ok, that's enough information for me to do something about it. thank you very much!